# Modifying a firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can I get the original .xpi file of an extension so that I can make changes to it?

Comment: An .xpi is just a zip file with an .xpi extension. So you can also just get the unzipped *contents* of the xpi at C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<your profile name>\extensions (if you're on Windows 7. On other systems it will be somewhere roughly equivalent.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Alt-click the green <kbd>Add to Firefox</kbd> button in the extension page to save the `.xpi` file to disk.